# UML Class Diagram Primary Key in Visio 2007

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram

How do I show Primary and Foreign keys in Visio 2007? I'm completely stumped. All my research so far shows how to do it in 2003 but nothing for 2007.

Thank You in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is a term from the SQL world.
UML class diagrams, however, are not about databases. :)

[This should help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282383/primary-foreign-keys-in-uml)